# error TF255146 in installing tfs 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

I researched about to solve this **errors** :

```
TF255146: Team Foundation Server requires SQL Server 2012 SP1 (11.00.3000) or greater.  The SQL Server instance SERVER\sql2012 you supplied is version 11.0.2100.60.

TF255507: The security identifier (SID) for the following SQL Server login conflicts with a specified domain or workgroup account: WIN-3QKNH40DUMD\Administrator. The domain or workgroup account is: SERVER\Administrator.  The server selected to host the databases for Team Foundation Server is: SERVER\sql2012. 
You can resolve this issue by renaming the conflicting login. To do so, open a command prompt on the computer that is running SQL Server and execute the following command:
sqlcmd -E -S "SERVER\sql2012" -Q "ALTER LOGIN [WIN-3QKNH40DUMD\Administrator] WITH NAME = [SERVER\Administrator]"
For more information, see the following page on the Microsoft Web site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=183408
```

how can I fix it ?
and I dont need to install `sharepoint` and reporting service. I searched a lot to find and fix this errors but failed !

Answer (score 0):

Have you renamed your machine after installing SQL?

I'd suggest rebuilding your server from scratch.  If you want to choose a different machine name, make sure you do that before installing SQL (or anything else).

Then install SQL 2012 SP1, then TFS 2013 and you should be good to go.

Comment: yes i renamed machine and thanks a lot for you answer...so i dont have anything to do to solve this without reinstalling sql srever ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SP1 for SQL Server 2012.  TFS 2013 does not support SQL Server 2012 without SP1.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185/en-us